# How can I recover a Stack Overflow account with just a username - no email?

Tags: support, login, accounts

I have a 10-year-old SO account that I used to log in with username and password. I still have those credentials. I tried to log in again today after being inactive for over one year, but now there isn't any option in the login page to identify only with username—the page requires an email. I don't have any idea if I ever associated an email with this account. How can I get my account back?

I tried looking for a page that accepts a username to log in, and I also searched for any information about changes that made username login impossible. I also tried looking for a support form.

Comment: you would have to use the contact us tool.

Comment: I looked for something like that and I couldn't find it. Can you provide a link? Thanks.

Comment: on the bottom of this page. In the Company section.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/contact?referrer=https://stackoverflow.co

Comment: I admit, however, that I doubt you'd have been able to use a username to log in last year, or *many* years ago; usernames aren't unique on [so].

Comment: @ThomA - There was a [Stack Exchange Stack (OpenID)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647/support-for-openid-ended-on-july-25-2018) option that was discontinued several years ago. The ability to do so was removed more than a year ago.

Comment: I forgot about OpenID, @SecurityHound , though you're right, support for that ended in July 2018.